# Excel, IF formula, logical test between

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am having some trouble with an if formula.

```
=IF(K2>0.75,BK2*$AZ$2,BK2*$BA$2)
```

I want to make it so, IF K2 > .75 and <1.25 or between these numbers then multiply BK2 by -1 if its not between then multiply by -.01 .

In my formula AZ2 is -1 and BA2 is -.01

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If K2 is greater than .75, and less than 1.25, or **between these two numbers**? So if it's greater than .75, less than 1.25 or between .75 and 1.25?? Would that not be every number?  Or do you mean any number *except* 1.25 and .75?

Comment: For example if K2 is 100, it should multiply BK2 by -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, this should do it:

```
=IF(AND(K2>75,K2<125),BK2*$AZ$2,BK2*$BA$2)
```

So if K2 is over 75, but less than 125, it'll multiply `BK2` by `AZ2`

Comment: It seems like the logic is reversed, I am getting the result for -.01 when k2 is 100 for me.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to get? Your comment on the OP says "If K2 is 100, multiply BK2 by -1", but your post leads me to think that I would multiply by -.01, since 100 is not between .75 and 1.25?

Comment: I am sorry, my fault. I was thinking 75 to 125 lol.

Comment: @excelguy - See the edit.